# CentOS: adding static route to outer network via another gateway in the same network

Tags: centos, routing

Given: CentOS 6 computer working as default gateway for local net. Its internal net is 10.20.30.0/24, 10.20.30.1 is its IP address.

Problem: I need to set up static route to another network (i.e. 10.40.10.0/24), via gateway 10.20.30.5 (in the same internal net).

When I add static route on any local system, i.e.

```
Linux:
route add -net 10.40.10.0/24 gw 10.20.30.5 
Windows:
route add 10.40.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.20.30.5
```

it works fine. However, I see no obvious way to add corresponding routing on default gateway only, to avoid adding static routes on every local computer.

If I do on default gateway something like

```
ip route add 10.40.10.0/24 via 10.20.30.5 dev eth1
```

(eth1 is where 10.20.30.0/24 works), I see ICMP Ping traveling back and forth to 10.40.10.0/24, but all other communication with that network times out.

**Updated**: as requested in comments:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:xx:xx:xx:xx:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 8x.yy.zz.a/24 brd 8x.yy.zz.255 scope global eth0
    inet 8x.yy.zz.b/24 brd 8x.yy.zz.255 scope global secondary eth0:0
    inet 8x.yy.zz.c/24 brd 8x.yy.zz.255 scope global secondary eth0:1
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:tttt/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:xx:yy:zz:tt:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.30.1/24 brd 10.20.30.255 scope global eth1
    inet 10.21.0.1/16 brd 10.21.255.255 scope global eth1:0
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:yyyy:zzzz:tttt/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: Can you post your network configuration?

    ip addr

and

    cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

Comment: @Alessandro Carini Done, post updated.